# How to init Fastlane for a multi-flavor Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, fastlane, android-flavors

I'm working on a Flutter app targeting both iOS and Android, and I use Codemagic for my CI.

Since Codemagic doesn't provide any native feature to automatically upload the screenshots to the stores, I want to try to achieve that by using Fastlane, since Fastlane is already installed on Codemagic machines (but any other option is welcomed).

I'm new to Fastlane and I try to init Fastlane for the Android (and same for iOS) part of my Flutter app.

So as per the documentation, I ran `fastlane init` on my `android` directory.

But at some point, I need to enter the package name. But since my app has 2 flavors, and therefore 2 package names, I don't know how I should setup Fastlane in this kind of situation.

So how can I properly setup Fastlane for my two flavors (Android and / or iOS)?

Thanks for your help.